# URL API parser alternative for Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, webapi, urlparse

The javascript used by Google Scripts does not include the URI API library for parsing URLs. It also does not support complex (perl-like backwards looking) regular expressions. As far as I know you can't import public libraries. This makes it hard, verbose and unreliable to parse out URL elements.

However it does support web calls through URLFetchApp and the REST API. **Is there a parsing server out in the internet that hosts the URI API, which can be called by URLFetchApp or using the built in REST API?** I can not find one easily. Other solutions welcome.

I have a working solution only for US based URLs. International URLs break my regEx. I prefer using a robust solution not dependent on regEx.

If you want to know the problem dealing with....
I need to compare two URLs and see if the 2nd url is a on a subdomain, or directory or same as the home page.

```
function scoreURL (urlOne,urlTwo){

  let regexSubdomain = /(?:http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+)(\/.*)?/;

  var urlOneArray = urlOne.split(regexSubdomain);
  var urlTwoArray = urlTwo.split(regexSubdomain);
  var subdomainOne = urlOneArray[1].replace(new RegExp('www.','i'),'')
  var subdomainTwo = urlTwoArray[1].replace(new RegExp('www.','i'),'')

// return -1 if landing page is on sub domais, 0 if landing page is separate page , 1 if landing page is home page
  if (subdomainOne === subdomainTwo) {
    if (urlOneArray[2] === urlTwoArray[2])
      {return (1);} else {return(0);}
    } else return (-1);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: Input is two url strings with the base same domain. Example "http://offer.website.com/signup", "website.com". Output -1 if one of the string is using a subdomain, 0 if direct match, 1 if a subdirectory is used in one of the string, I should add -2 if domains don't match. The output is not so important as the ability to get the domain and subdomain in each string.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted and the discussions have been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussions.

Answer (score 0):

- The basic [URL api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) links to a polyfill [`core-js` module](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#url-and-urlsearchparams).
- The [URL polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/web.url.js) uses  multiple `require` statements that are not directly supported in apps script.
- You can manually copy paste all `require`d files from the parent directory and remove all `require`d dependencies OR
- Use [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) in your local [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) to transpile the polyfill

  - install webpack and corejs

    ```
    mkdir webpack
    cd webpack
    npm init -y
    npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
    npm install --save core-js@3.18.3
    ```
  - src/index.js:

    ```
    import 'core-js/web/url'
    ```
  - Bundle with webpack

    ```
    npx webpack
    ```
  - Copy the resulting bundled js(in `dist/main.js`) to a file(`url.gs`) in apps script.
- You'll now be able to use `URL`, `URLSearchParams` in global scope.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm using Google Scripts, which means it is hosted at Google. This does not allow for installing new libraries or importing them. It why I asked if there are parsing servers which can be connected to using the REST API.

Comment: @ThePirate Transpilation is the process of converting libraries to pure JavaScript. I tested this method and I can use  `new URL()` in apps script.

Comment: Alright I'll look into it before I ask more questions. Thank you.