# How do I remove contractions from a document in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, libraries

I fundamentally know what to do, I just need some help on the actual removal. I used [kontractions](https://github.com/johncmunson/kontractions) for the library and used this snippet to add it in:

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("<SCRIPT>").getContentText())
const LIBRARIES = {<SCRIPT REFERENCE>: "<SCRIPT>", <ANOTHER SCRIPT REFERENCE>: "<ANOTHER SCRIPT>"}
Object.keys(LIBRARIES).forEach(function(library) { newFunc = eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(LIBRARIES[library]).getContentText()); eval('var ' + library + ' = ' + newFunc); });
```

but the library imports others and I can't put in all of them. Is there any way I can do this without completely rewriting it altogether?

Comment: Is the source of your text a Google Doc?  And "ain't" has several translations, how to know which you want?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69578680